# how to enter the push notification into the database even if it is cleared from the notification bar of device without clicking it

Tags: ios, parse-platform, push-notification, xcode6

I want to get the parse push notification in my app's database even if it is cleared from the notification bar without opening it, when my app is in background.  Please help me. Thanks in advance.

Comment: What have you tried? What is the issue? Can you share some code? We are not here to code in your place.

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to save it with application database without opening it.